# Обобщения по Шилдту закрытый / открытый тип

Tags: c#, .net

Господа, учу обобщения по Шилдту и наткнулся на такую вот цитату:

> C# чаще определяются такие понятия,
> как открытый и закрытый типы. Открытым
> типом считается такой параметр типа
> или любой обобщенный тип, для которого
> аргумент типа является параметром типа
> или же включает его в себя. А любой
> тип, не относящийся к открытому,
> считается закрытым. Сконструированным
> типом считается такой обобщенный тип,
> для которого предоставлены все
> аргументы типов. Если все эти
> аргументы относятся к закрытым типам,
> то такой тип считается закрыто
> сконструированным. А если один или
> несколько аргументов типа относятся к
> открытым типам, то такой тип считается
> открыто сконструированным.

Если честно, то не понял ни слова из этой фразы. Понял лишь, что сконструированный тип - это тип, которому выписали аргументы. А вот что такое открытый и закрытый тип - вообще не въехал. Если не трудно, объясните, пожалуйста, на пальцах, что это значит (открыты/закрытый тип).
Буду дико благодарен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как я понял, этот текст имеет в виду отличие generic-типа, в котором есть конкретные типы-аргументы, и типа, в котором их нет (`List<int>` против `List<T>` для generic-параметра `T`).

И кстати: не советую учить по Шилдту. Он был не очень хорошим автором, и вряд ли стал лучше.

Comment: >И кстати: не советую учить по Шилдту. Он был не очень хорошим автором, и вряд ли стал лучш

не стану говорить насчет Шилдта, не читал, однако в данном случае налицо отвратительный перевод. Из какого издательства, интересно, этот надмозг?

Comment: @DreamChild таковое заимствование как бы намекаэ...

Answer (score 3):

эта ваша книга случайно не гуглопереводчиком переведена? Давно не встречал такого косноязычия. Если у вас  книга переведена автоматически, то найдите нормальный перевод. Если же перлы типа "C# чаще определяются такие понятия" - дело рук человека-переводчика, то такому толмачу надо забить гвоздь в голову. Я не первый год работаю с шарпом, но в этом заклинании честно говоря  тоже мало что понял

Comment: @DreamChild это какое-то руководство  http://professorweb.ru/my/csharp/charp_theory/level11/11_2.php

Comment: @smackmychi насколько я знаю, материалы этого сайта представляют собой переписанные книги. То есть этот текст взят именно из книги (по всей вероятности как раз из Шилдта)

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас посмотрю. Нет это именно книга, печатное издание... Называется с# 4.0 полное руководство стр. 580

Answer (score 1):

Нашел пример отличия типов на MSDN:

```
class BaseNode { }
class BaseNodeGeneric<T> { }

// concrete type
class NodeConcrete<T> : BaseNode { }

//closed constructed type
class NodeClosed<T> : BaseNodeGeneric<int> { }

//open constructed type
class NodeOpen<T> : BaseNodeGeneric<T> { }
```

https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-classes

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).